# How do I override the_excerpt so that it will display full content?

Tags: filters, excerpt

I am creating a plugin. Many themes display excerpt such as when `is_search()` is `1`.

I want WordPress to display full content no matter what.

How would I do so?

Should I use `add_filter ('the_excerpt', 'mycontentfunction' );`

Should I use `add_filter` or `apply_filters`?

Comment: Add_filter is right. Apply_filter is to define filter and accept callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code should do the trick.  It takes the excerpt filter and returns the content instead.

```
function wpse189347_excerpt( $excerpt ){
    return get_the_content();
}

add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse189347_excerpt', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: It's tempting to use this *abusive* one-liner: `add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'the_content' ); ` to support all the content filters, since we don't need to return the value here ;-)

Comment: That works, too, except you'd want to use `get_the_content`, since you are trying to return something.  Edit: looking at it now, probably not a good idea, since the excerpt gets inputted in as an argument.

Comment: The method I mentioned is totally ignoring `the_excerpt`  and just runs `the_content()` instead, so that's why I called it *abusive* ;-) It's like short circuiting `the_excerpt()`, by throwing out  `the_content()` and returning `null` for the rest of `the_excerpt` filters. We also note that `get_the_content()` doesn't give the same output as `the_content()`. Just wanted to mention this, but I'm not recommending it ;-)

Comment: birgie, I selected this as the answer. If you put your abusive technique as an answer and it works, I'll put it too.